# GCP cannot create Managed Notebook on Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Using a GCP account that started as free, but does have billing enabled, I can't create a managed notebook and get the following popup error:

Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Create Runtime API requests' and limit 'Create Runtime API requests per minute' of service 'notebooks.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:....'

Navigating to Quotas --> Notebook API --> Create Runtime API requests per minute

Edit Quota: Create Runtime API requests per minute
Current limit: 0
Enter a new quota limit between 0 and 0.

0 doesn't work..

Is there something that I can do, or should have done already to increase this quota?

TIA for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed notebooks is still pre-GA and is currently unavailable to the projects with insufficient service usage history.

You can wait for the GA of the service or use a project with more service usage.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems worth waiting for.